# How can Boolean system form a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

According to the definition of vector space, if u, v and w are two objects of a set(S)  and there are two functions namely Addition(+) and multiplication (.) defines on the set, then the set forms a vector space iff the following axioms are obeyed 
1)  u+v=k where k belongs to S.
2) u+v=v+u
3)( u+v)+w=u+(v+w)
4) There is a zero vector O such that
   u+O=u and O belongs to S.
5) for each u there’s a vector -u such that u+(-u)=O
 (c and d are scalars)
6) c(u) belongs to S
7)c(u+v)=c(u)+c(v)
8)(c+d)u=c(u)+c(v)
9)c(du)=(cd)u
10)1.u=u
In Boolean, addition is defined as OR and multiplication as AND, so the axiom 5) does not hold, then how does Boolean form space?

Comment: What does "-" mean in the booleans? And what does "O" mean? Knowing that, what can you say about $u+(-u)$?

Comment: No, addition is defined as XOR.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd consider the set of all $n$-ary Boolean functions $f:B^n\rightarrow B$, where $B=\{0,1\}$.
It forms a vector space with the addition operation
$$(f + g)(x) = f(x)\oplus f(x)$$
and the scalar multiplication
$$(af)(x) = a\wedge f(x),\quad a\in B,$$
where $\oplus$ is the logical xor (mod 2) and $\wedge$ is the logical and.